# Fixed-width non-FIFO DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, asynchronous, concurrency, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have implemented a custom concurrent queue on top of GCD which offers two additional pieces of functionality:

1. Limit the maximum number of concurrently executing tasks.
2. Give manual control over which enqueued task is scheduled for execution next.

An `OperationQueue` could of course address the former but gives no control over the latter. Being able to influence the order in which the queue executes its task is however beneficial for the purposes of my app (anticipating and delaying expensive tasks that are likely to get cancelled), hence my attempt at this implementation.

I have multiple concerns:

1. The fact that this is *one* class providing *two* distinct pieces of functionality seems like a red flag. Implementing this in two separate types, possibly with one subclassing the other, would probably be better. But I can't see a straightforward way to untangle this without overcomplicating things.
2. Needing three queues and a semaphore to coordinate everything isn't great. Am I trying to be too clever?
3. Looking through some of the [libdispatch guidelines](https://gist.github.com/tclementdev/6af616354912b0347cdf6db159c37057), particularly [this post by the maintainer](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170828/039405.html), has me wondering if this entire use case is a bit of an anti-pattern anyway (specifically regarding the use of semaphores to wait for asynchronous work). Is it simply a bad idea to try retrofitting this kind of functionality onto GCD?

Given my initial requirements (i.e. limited bandwidth and custom scheduling order), is this approach remotely reasonable? If so, how could it be improved?

Thanks in advance!

```swift
final class Queue {

    let count: Int

    private let block: (Range<Int>) -> Int

    private let semaphore: DispatchSemaphore

    private let objectQueue: DispatchQueue

    private let semaphoreQueue: DispatchQueue

    private let workItemQueue: DispatchQueue

    private var workItems = Array<DispatchWorkItem>()

    init(count: Int, qos: DispatchQoS = .default, block: @escaping (Range<Int>) -> Int) {
        self.count = count

        self.block = block

        self.semaphore = .init(value: count)

        self.objectQueue = .init(label: "object-queue", qos: qos)

        self.semaphoreQueue = .init(label: "semaphore-queue", qos: qos)

        self.workItemQueue = .init(label: "workitem-queue", qos: qos, attributes: [.concurrent])
    }

}

extension Queue {

    func async(execute work: @escaping () -> ()) {
        objectQueue.async { [self] in
            let workItem = DispatchWorkItem(flags: [.inheritQoS]) {
                work()

                semaphore.signal()
            }

            workItems.append(workItem)

            semaphoreQueue.async {
                semaphore.wait()

                objectQueue.async {
                    let index = block(workItems.indices)

                    let workItem = workItems.remove(at: index)

                    workItemQueue.async(execute: workItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func async(execute workItem: DispatchWorkItem) {
        async { workItem.perform() }
    }

}
```

**Edit**

The `block` closure selects the index of the next-to-be-scheduled work item. Its argument `Range` is guaranteed to be non-empty.

The work items are in the same order in which they were enqueued. `block` isn't intended to relate to specific work items but rather to make a decision between choosing ones that have been awaiting execution for a while vs. ones that just arrived in the queue.

I use it in this specific way:

```swift
let count = max(1, ProcessInfo.processInfo.activeProcessorCount - 2)

let queue = Queue(count: count) { indices in
    let value = sqrt(.random(in: 0 ..< 1))

    let index = Int(value * Double(indices.count))

    return indices[index]
}
```

In this configuration the queue picks work items at random, *skewing towards newer ones*. This might seem counterintuitive, but when dealing with a lot of expensive tasks which are subject to likely cancellation (in my case loading resources for display in a collection view while scrolling), this results in a measurable performance improvement.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the `block` callback is called when an execution  slot is available, and that returns the index of the next work item to be executed. But how does the callback make that decision bases on *indices* only, if there is no (public) correspondence between the indices and the work items? – A small usage example might be helpful.

Comment: Btw, your code fails to compile in my Xcode 12 with some “Missing argument for parameter 'label' in call“ errors.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, I forgot I had an extension on `DispatchQueue` to automatically generate a label.

Comment: @MartinR Added an example use case.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're doing here that simply setting `queuePriority` for operations added to an `OperationQueue` would not achieve. E.g. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKvLL.png) I added 25 low priority tasks (in green) to a queue with a max concurrency of 6, then added 25 normal priority tasks (in yellow), and the operation queue correctly prioritized the higher priority tasks ahead of the low priority tasks that were added to the queue before the default priority tasks (as soon as, of course, the queue was free).

Comment: @Rob I am dealing with tasks that have all inherently the same priority. The ability to control the order of execution such that e.g. more recent task are treated preferentially can help with making the UI feel more responsive when the user demands many expensive resources in quick succession. Scrolling a collection view of images is an example. No individual image is more important than another while scrolling is in progress, but as soon as it stops, it makes sense to load the latest images first, instead of working yourself through the queue back to front.

Comment: @Rob The fact that this approach allows to introduce an element of randomness to the order of execution is also quite important to me, as it enables interesting effects in the UI. It feels subjectively faster to me, to not present resources in the "obvious" order sometimes.

Comment: OK, I now understand your intent. Personally, I'd suggest that you need priorities, too, where the currently visible cells are medium priority, where the prefetched cells are low priority, and the cells that have scrolled out of view are very low priority, or simply canceled. You never want it fetching a cell that you don't yet need or don't need any more before you fetch the images for the visible cells. Now, if within those constraints, you also want randomness, fine, add that. But I don't think you want to rely solely on a probability curve (which is in effect what your approach is doing).

Comment: @Rob The thing is that for use cases like this, what is essentially needed are *dynamic* priorities. Currently needed resources can become unnecessary before they get a chance to load, prefetched resources can become needed immediately, etc. Associating a certain priority with a given task is (in my opinion) only really a good model if the priority is expected to be fixed, otherwise you are signing yourself up for a lot of bookkeeping.

Comment: @Rob Of coures you still don't want to load more resources than are actually needed, but I find that this is more easily accomplished within the body of the task itself. Check for relevance / cache volume / other metrics before you load the resource and abort of necessary.

Comment: Yep, agreed re dynamic priorities. I am merely suggesting that a single, non-uniform distribution function is suboptimal, and you might instead want a notion of priority classes, and then some distribution within each (e,g., low priority LIFO for for cells that have scrolled out of view; random, evenly distributed for visible cells; and low priority FIFO for prefetched cells; ie fetch what you need now first, and then next prioritize the ones that may scroll into view soonest).

Comment: Re dispatch vs operation queues, I'd lean towards the latter if when dealing with dependencies between tasks that are themselves asynchronous. Dispatch work items won't wait until the task is finished unless you block the worker thread until the task is done. That having been said, I would probably abandon both dispatch and operation queues for this sort of dynamic prioritization (as they are both inherently FIFO queues and you have to contort yourself to get the dynamic and randomization logic you are looking for). I'll post something this weekend if you are interested.

Comment: @Rob I agree, splitting things up across multiple queues with different behaviors could be a reasonable optimization (at least for the specific example of scrolling through resources). But it also introduces further complexity and requires knowledge about the properties of the task at the point of enqueueing. Plus it wouldn't necessarily generalize to other use cases, but maybe that's a good thing.

Comment: @Rob I would be very interested in an approach that doesn't use GCD or operation queues at all. I'm more than a little wary of my code, hence the question.